# Calling a method from another class draws no error but doesnt work

Tags: java, methods

I am creating a task manager program which can manage information about a task such as the deadline, how long the task is expected to take and more. To this i have a class called Task, one called TaskManager and one called Deadline.

When trying to tell the Task manager to search for the task by ID, then call the method setDone from Task there is no error, but it makes no changes to the programs state. Can anyone show me where i could be going wrong?

```
public Task setCompleted(int completeId) {
    for (Task task : tasks) {
        if (task.getId()==(completeId)) {
            Task setDone;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The code above is where i am trying to call the method, the code below is the method from Task.

```
public void setDone() {              
    this.done = true;             
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `task.setDone()` instead of `Task setDone`?

Comment: What do you think happens at this line `Task setDone;` ?

Comment: Why have a method that always returns `null`? Why not make it `void`? Or, of course, actually return a non-null `Task`?

Comment: The return null part should probably be an else statement, but that's part of our briefing. the Task setDone part im hoping to change the property of the object within TaskManager for whether the Task is done from its start state (false) to true. whenever i try Task.setDone() i get the error " ; expected" just before the double brackets.

Comment: Nonetheless, `Task setDone;` is only a declaration. It doesn't actually call a method. Also, it should be `task.setDone()`, not `Task.setDone()`. When you say `Task.setDone()` it will probably think you're trying to call a static method of your Task class that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Change your codes to:

```
if (task.getId()==completeId) {   
    task.setDone();
}
```

`setDone()` is a method belongs to Task object. Hence, you need a `.` and the braces.

Comment: *"It shall be "tasks" not "task""* I would love to know why you think it should be `tasks`.

Comment: @Tom According to OP's original code `for (Task task : tasks)`

Comment: Ah, OP wants to iterate the `tasks` iterable, just to call `getId` and `setDone` on that iterable, instead off on an item of it? I understand ...

Comment: @Tom I think it shall be task instead of tasks. He omitted a number of things in his codes such as the return statement and declaration of tasks.

Comment: I guess his/her `if (task.getId()==(completeId))` makes it clear, that it should be `task`, not `tasks` ;P.